# Transalation of tasks in .NET 1.1 to .NET 3.5

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, .net-1.1

In .Net  1.1 I would run a stored procedure to fill a typed dataset.  I would use a Datareader to fill the dataset for speed (though it was probably not necessary)

Then I would use the Dataset to bind to multiple controls on the page so as to render the data to multiple CSS/JavaScript based tabs on the page. This would also reduce the database call to **1**.

So I know I could this in 3.5, but is there a better way.

For example can one stored procedure create an EDM object to be used. Since the data is mainly readonly should I even bother changing or keep using the

```
Stored proc -> Data set -> Bind individual controls to specific data tables
```

Answer (score 0):

Rule #1... if it ain't broke, don't fix it.  Is this a performance issue with the current implementation?  If not, leave it alone.  You're not going to get any faster than ONE db call no matter how you slice it, unless you can make it 0 db calls.

Comment: True, but what's the newer analogy to my conundrum. 
EDM with stack the database calls, but is there a way to load an from a Stored proc...

Or this doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm not familiar with EDM at all, so can't really answer that question.  I just know that stored procs aren't going to give you any real performance advantage over other methods as long as you're executing the same SQL code.